# cloud build trigger in app engine -Nodejs runtime error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, runtime

WARNING:  Your package.json does not specify a supported Node.js version.  Please pin your application to a major version of the Node.js runtime.

Application detection failed: Error: node.js checker: Neither "start" in the "scripts" section of "package.json" nor the "server.js" file were found.

I added below in package.json
"engines": {
"node": "^13.8.0",
"npm":"^6.13.4"
},
app.yaml file

```
 # [START runtime]
    runtime: nodejs
    env: flex
    service: dev
    
    handlers:
    - url: /.*
      secure: always
      script: auto
      redirect_http_response_code: 301
    
    automatic_scaling:
      min_num_instances: 1
      max_num_instances: 2
      cool_down_period_sec: 60
      cpu_utilization:
        target_utilization: 0.80
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "serve -s ./build",
        "prestart": "npm i -g serve",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    }
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  entrypoint: 'npm'
  args: [ install ]

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  entrypoint: 'npm'
  args: [ run, build, --prod ]


- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  entrypoint: 'npm'
  args: [ app, deploy, '[public/app.yaml]', --version=$SHORT_SHA ]
```

Comment: were you able to solve it ? I have the same issue. I have package.json file also it has start script. but still i am getting same error

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the GAE standard, keep in mind that it currently supports Node.js 10 and 12 [runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#node.js-12).

Also, as the official GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#application_startup) mentions:

> By default, the runtime starts your application by running node
> **server.js**. If you specify a start script in your package.json file,
> the runtime runs the specified start script instead.
>
> ```
> "scripts": {
>   "start": "node app.js"
> }
> ```

Please, have a look at [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/hello-world/standard) GitHub repository, which contains a simple app for GAE standard, which you could use as a reference.

---

### EDIT

You need to **make sure that your start script is starting a web server** that responds to HTTP requests on the port specified by the PORT environment variable, typically 8080 ([link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime)).

[Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/hello-world/flexible) you can see an example for the GAE flexible environment, where the **app.js** contains

```
// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
```

While the **package.json** has

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
}
```

This error can be reproduced when [deploying](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-appengine#configuring_the_deployment) that sample on GAE with Cloud Build after removing the start script or if the app is not starting the server.

Comment: I changed in pacakge.json with above code"engines": { "node": "^12.0.0", "npm":"^6.13.4" } but still I get the same error app.yaml file any change shuld be done?

Comment: The error you get is saying `Neither "start" in the "scripts" section of "package.json" nor the "server.js" file were found`. Could you try adding the start script in your **package.json** file as mentioned in the GCP documentation I linked?

Comment: If it doesn't help, please update your question adding the contents of your *package.json* and *app.yaml* files, as well as a minimal reproducible code of your application. Please remember to remove any sensitive information these files may include.